# How to extract xz files in FLutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, lzma, xz

I need to decompress xz files in my flutter app. I have tried unsuccessfully the lzma plugin.

Is there any way to decompress xz files in my app?

Answer (score 1):

First add archive to your dependency:

```
flutter pub add archive
```

Now import them:

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'package:archive/archive.dart';
```

Here is a simple demo that will extract file in Home Directory/extractedTemp

```
   Future<void> extract() async {
    
        final xzFilePath = state.path;
        Map<String, String> envVars = Platform.environment;
        String? home = envVars['HOME'];
        final outputDirectory = "${home}/extractedTemp";
    
        // Read the XZ file into a Uint8List
        final xzBytes = File(xzFilePath).readAsBytesSync();
    
        // Decompress the XZ file
        final decompressedBytes = decompressXZ(xzBytes);
    
        // Extract the contents of the archive
        extractArchive(decompressedBytes, outputDirectory);
    
        print('Extraction completed successfully.');
      }
    
      List<int> decompressXZ(Uint8List input) {
        // Create a XZDecoder and decode the input
        final xzDecoder = XZDecoder();
        return xzDecoder.decodeBytes(input);
      }
    
      void extractArchive(List<int> input, String outputDirectory) {
        // Create an Archive and extract its contents
        final archive = TarDecoder().decodeBytes(input);
    
        for (final file in archive) {
          if (file.isFile) {
            final filePath = '$outputDirectory/${file.name}';
            File(filePath)
              ..createSync(recursive: true)
              ..writeAsBytesSync(file.content as List<int>);
            print('Extracted: $filePath');
          }
        }
      }
```

It's working fine.